# How to generate client-side code for multiple WCF services with shared types

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy, svcutil.exe

I have multiple WCF services that share some data contracts and need to generate client-side code using svcutil.exe. I've run into errors using two most obvious ways to do this and need some help.

But first, here are the services:

```
[ServiceContract( Namespace = "http://www.me.com/services/" )]
public interface IFooService {
    [OperationContract]
    Response RunFoo( Request request );
}
[ServiceContract( Namespace = "http://www.me.com/services/" )]
public interface IBarService {
    [OperationContract]
    Response RunBar( Request request );
}
```

Response and Request are defined in a separate assembly:

```
[DataContract( Namespace = "http://www.me.com/shared/" )]
public class Request {
    [DataMember]
    public int Input { get; set; }
}
[DataContract( Namespace = "http://www.me.com/shared/" )]
public class Response {
    [DataMember]
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

The services are implemented in some trivial way, compiled, published - let's switch to the client side now.

Including both services on the svcutil command line - like this:

```
svcutil /o:Client.cs http://hostname.com/FooService.svc http://hostname.com/BarService.svc
```

will result in numerous error messages about duplicated data types, starting with

> Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
>       Source:
>       Line: 1 Column: 9087
>      Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:anyType' has already been declared.

and ending with

> Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
>       Source:
>       Line: 1 Column: 12817
>      Validation Error: The complexType 'http://www.me.com/shared/:Response' has already been declared.

Generating a client-side file separately for each service avoids these errors:

```
svcutil /o:Foo.cs http://hostname.com/FooService.svc
svcutil /o:Bar.cs http://hostname.com/BarService.svc
```

But then definitions of shared types (such as Request and Response) will be duplicated in Foo.cs and then in Bar.cs, resulting obviously in compiler errors.

So, **what is the conventional way to generate client-side code consuming such services**?

Limitations:

- cannot ship an assembly containing shared types to the client (so that they could use svcutil.exe's /r option)
- cannot use the "Add Service Reference..." command in Visual Studio - need an svcutil command line (or another command-line tool).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, basically you can

- either put your shared types into a separate assembly that the clients can use when generating the client code (which you already dismiss as impossible)

or then:

- you have to generate each proxy for the services separately, and each service will get its own "copy" of the "Request" and "Response" classes

Either you **can** share the common assembly - or you **can't** - I don't see any other choice, really.

Comment: But it's not an either-or situation. By specifying multiple endpoints to svcutil on the commandline, you can generate ONE set of output files that reuse DTOs across multiple services. No need to reuse the assembly from the service side, and no need for each service to have it's own copies of the same objects.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have rules out a shared DTO assembly (why, btw?), the simplest option in this case *looks* to be to generate the types in different C# namespaces (i.e. two calls to `svcutil`), and map the data between the two. Essentially: treat the DTOs from the two services as coincidentally similar.

You can use things like automapper to reduce the work, or you could juts serialize from type A and deserialize into type B (assuming the actual *data* namespaces etc are identical).

Comment: The server and the clients are in different organizations. So, I have to either reach out to every client and give them the DLL or turn it into a downloadable or open-source product.  In any case, that would involve more people and be a more difficult and expensive decision than when a developer simply picks the right combination of  command-line options.

Answer (score 2):

WSCF Blue may get you closer to a solution if you've not found one already.

http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/

It can produce separate files for each type, overwriting on subsequent operations.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the client utility once you will get a XXXXService.cs and a output.config file.

If you observe the XXXXService class you have everything in a file. You can split these as a seperate IXXXService and XXXService file and the datacontracts file.

Then you can run the utility for the second service and add IXXXService1.cs and 1XXXService.cs file and the same datacontracts you can use to share for these 2.

I am not sure if this can answer your question. I had [an example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NContracts1Service) which can help you.
You can see some more examples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/UserAccount/UserProfile.aspx?UserName=aditya) related to some MVC and WCF stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please download WSCFblue-v1-Walkthrough zip from the below link, it might help you acheive it.

http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/releases/view/48529